# Make paper.js PointText editable with a cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, paperjs

I'm using an image annotation tool for a website I'm working on, and I need to type text onto the `canvas` using the `paper.js` `PointText` object. That part is pretty easy. I'd also like to be able to type with a visible cursor, and edit, create/change multiple lines, save it, and edit it again.

It's the part with typing with a cursor and editing in the middle of it that I'm wondering if it is even possible. Right now, I can type and delete letters, but only at the end of the text I've already created. I want to edit in the middle without deleting anything.

I'm not posting much code because my question is theoretical, and I haven't been able to find any code to try, except for the `jQuery` attribute `contentEditable`.

```
$(text).attr('contentEditable');
```

where `text` is a `paper.PointText(position)` object at position `event.point`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try placing a `contenteditable` div over the canvas when you click on the `PointText`.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/maitreyjukar/jz9Lu7wf/3/

Currently `paper.js` does not support `word-wrap` for `PointText`. They might provide support for it in `AreaText` which, hopefully, should be available shortly.

Comment: That code looks amazing and just like what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I've already created a work around so I can't test it personally, but since it appears to work amazingly, I will accept this answer. `AreaText` sounds awesome.

Comment: Fiddle is broken